# 2004 Honda CRV low RPM, stalls whenever I ease off the accelerator

Tags: honda, stall, crv

I have a 2004 Honda CRV with around 220,000 km on the odometer. The vehicle won't start unless I'm pressing on the accelerator, and it will stall if I'm not constantly revving it. My wife says that this started over a month ago, and at the time it was something where simply revving it a bit on the initial start was enough to stabilize it, and after the vehicle had 5 to 20 seconds of revving to warm it up, the problem didn't resurface for the rest of the drive.

Now it's worse. If I'm at a stoplight it will stall, and so I have to start it again and jam it into drive and accelerate in order to keep it from dying. I've heard that this issue is sometimes caused by a sensor, I disconnected the negative battery terminal for over an hour and when I reconnected it the problem remained.

There is a check engine light on, but this has been on for the past year due to a unrelated issue, I think it was the catalytic converter. Hoping to borrow a code reader tomorrow to check it out, but is there anything I should try out in the meantime?

I'm not the most mechanically inclined guy out there, so if the fix requires a lot of dicking around I will probably just bring it to a mechanic, but I'm willing to give it the old college try before hand.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!